# Gitkraken doesn't list GitHub repositories for cloning

Tags: git, gitkraken

I stopped using gitkraken for serveral months. When I try to clone a repo with it today, it doesn't list my GitHub repo. This functionality works fine on my other computers, I guessed the OAuth token for GitHub was expired, but I couldn't find the option to refresh the token. I tried to disconnect GitHub integration from preference, but it doesn't allow me to logout because I signed in with GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is to remove `~/.gitkraken` folder, but all cache would be removed, all repos open will be closed.

Solution that works for me: go to

- Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\.gitkraken\profiles\<some profile id>`
- Mac/Linux: `~/.gitkraken/profiles/<some profile id>`

Remove github folder, and restart gitkraken, you will have a chance to connect to GitHub again.